# Не могу понять суть кода триггера (Firebird)

Tags: firebird

В интернете нашёл пример создания системы безопасности(Firebird) но не могу понять что представлет собой слово **USER**  в триггере?

часть триггера и её обоснованность изложена так:

> Сначала определяем кто пытается создать новую запись и какими правами
>   он обладает и отмечаем это в полях new.UsrCreate и new.UsrModify:

```
 Select USERID, USRRole,USRLevel from USERS where USERNAME=USER into
          :USR,:Rls,:Lev;
 new.USRRole = new.USRGroup||Cast(new.USRLevel as Char(1)); 
 new.UsrCreate = USR;
 new.USRModify  = USR;
```

Полностью код создания таблицы и триггера выглядит так:

```
  Create table USERS
          (USERID       AZMID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
           USERNAME     AZNAMES  NOT NULL UNIQUE, -- Login из fbsecurity.fb (ISC4.gdb)
           USRSYSNAME   AZNAMES, -- из fbsecurity.fb (ISC4.gdb)
           USRDOMAIN    AZNAMES, -- из fbsecurity.fb (ISC4.gdb)
           USRNames     AZLNAME, -- Фамилия, Имя, Отчество
           USRNPost     AZLNAME, -- Должность

    /* ************************************************************************************************* */
           USRGroup     CHAR(1) character set win1251, -- Текущая группа доступа
           USRLevel     AZInt16 default 6,             -- Текущий уровень доступа
           USRRole      CHAR(2) character set Win1251, -- Допустимая группа  и уровень доступа
    /*Блок контроля - начало*/
           DtCreate     AZTStamp,
           UsrCreate    AZMID0,                   /*references USERS on UPDATE cascade*/
           DtModify     AZTStamp,
           UsrModify    AZMID0);                  /*references USERS on UPDATE cascade*/
    /*Блок контроля - конец*/
    Commit;





    SET TERM ^ ;
    CREATE TRIGGER USERS_INSERT FOR USERS
    ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 1 AS
    DECLARE VARIABLE USR SmallInt;
    DECLARE VARIABLE Cnt SmallInt;
    DECLARE VARIABLE Lev SmallInt;
    DECLARE VARIABLE Rls Char(2) character set win1251;
    BEGIN

    Select USERID, USRRole,USRLevel from USERS where USERNAME=USER into :USR,:Rls,:Lev;
    new.USRRole = new.USRGroup||Cast(new.USRLevel as Char(1)); 
    new.UsrCreate = USR;
    new.USRModify  = USR;
    IF (Lev>2) then Exception NoRoleInsert;
    END ^
    SET TERM ; ^
    Commit;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> CURRENT_USER is a context variable containing the name of the
>   currently connected user. It is fully equivalent to **USER**.

https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd15-current_user.html

Это служебная переменная, хранящая псевдоним текущего пользователя.

Триггер берёт текущего пользователя по псевдониму, проверяет его уровень доступа, и если он больше двух - то выкидывает исключение.

Comment: Zufir, CURRENT_USER знаю, но USER?  Это тоже самое?

Comment: Zufir, вы правы. 
https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/firebird_3_0_language_reference_rus.pdf
Переменная USER содержит имя текущего подключенного пользователя базы данных.
Тоже самое написано про CURRENT_USER.